# Datagrid binded to observable collection not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, bind, observablecollection

I have an observable collection **obcCfgPartPrograms** of the following class:

```
public class CfgPartPrograms: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public CfgPartPrograms() { }
    public string Group { get; set; }
    ...
    private bool _isImagePresent = false;
    public bool IsImagePresent
    {
       get { return _isImagePresent; }
       set { _isImagePresent = value; ...}<------HERE
    }
    public MyImage PpImage { get; set; }
}
```

That collection binds a datagrid through:

```
dtgFeatures.ItemsSource = obcCfgPartPrograms;
```

[image]

when I click on the IsImagePresent I want the set part of the IsImagePresent to be fired so that I can setUp the PpImage.
But that doesn't happen: when I click and having put a breakpoint nothin happens.
Thanx

Comment: OK, your binding may not be working. Mind showing us the binding?

Comment: Sorry I'm very poor at binding. See my edit

Comment: I'm not going to play this game with you. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Are there any binding errors that appear in the Output window? (Search for "Binding" if there's lots of stuff there). Another easy check would be to start these values off as True and see if the checkbox is then ticked. Also, while you've inherited the interface, I don't see any PropertyChanged notifications being raised (though this should only affect the updates going to the UX).

Comment: I can't see **INotifyPropertyChanged** implementation in the code you have posted. Do you raise the event after `_isImagePresent = value;`?

Comment: @PouyaAbadi The problem is that the _isImagePresent = value; is never hit.

Comment: Provide enough code to reproduce the issue, otherwise nobody can help you. Something in your code, either in your XAML or your C#, created this problem. We need to see enough code to spot the part that creates the problem.